# Nodejs streams - convert errors into default values

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm quite unfamiliar with streaming. Suppose I have an input stream:

```
let inputStream = fs.createReadStream(getTrgFilePath());
```

I'm going to pipe this input to some output stream:

```
inputStream.pipe(someGenericOutputStream);
```

In my case, `getTrgFilePath()` may not produce a valid filepath. This will cause a failure which will result in no content being sent to `someGenericOutputStream`.

How do I set things up so that when `inputStream` encounters an error, it pipes some default value (e.g. `"Invalid filepath!"`) instead of failing?

Example 1:

If `getTrgFilePath()` is invalid, and `someGenericOutputStream` is `process.stdout`, I want to see `stdout` say `"Invalid filepath!"`

Example 2:

If `getTrgFilePath()` is invalid, and `someGenericOutputStream` is the result of `fs.createOutputStream(outputFilePath)`, I would expect to find a file at `outputFilePath` with the contents `"Invalid filepath!"`.

I'm interested in a solution which doesn't need to know what specific kind of stream `someGenericOutputStream` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only worried about the path being invalid, you could first check the output with fs.access, but as I understand you don't want additional "handling" code in your file...

So let's take into account what may go wrong:

1. File path is not valid,
2. File or path does not exist,
3. File is not readable,
4. File is read but something happens when it fails.

Now I'm gonna leave the 4th case alone, this is a separate case, so we'll just ignore such a situation. We need two files (so that your code looks clean and all the mess is in a separate file) - here's the, lets say, `./lib/create-fs-with-default.js` file:

```
module.exports = // or export default  if you use es6 modules
    function(filepath, def = "Could not read file") {
        // We open the file normally
        const _in = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
        // We'll need a list of targets later on
        let _piped = [];
        // Here's a handler that end's all piped outputs with the default value.
        const _handler = (e) => {
            if (!_piped.length) {
                throw e;
            }

            _piped.forEach(
                out => out.end(def)
            );
        };
        _in.once("error", _handler);

        // We keep the original `pipe` method in a variable
        const _orgPipe = _in.pipe;
        // And override it with our alternative version...
        _in.pipe = function(to, ...args) {
            const _out = _orgPipe.call(this, to, ...args);

            // ...which, apart from calling the original, also records the outputs
            _piped.push(_out);
            return _out;
        }
        // Optionally we could handle `unpipe` method here.

        // Here we remove the handler once data flow is started.
        _in.once("data", () => _in.removeListener("error", _handler));
        // And pause the stream again so that `data` listener doesn't consume the first chunk.
        _in.pause();

        // Finally we return the read stream
        return _in;
    };
```

Now there's just a small matter to use it:

```
const createReadStreamWithDefault = require("./lib/create-fs-with-default");
const inputStream = fs.createReadStream(getTrgFilePath(), "Invalid input!");
// ... and at some point
inputStream.pipe(someOutput);
```

And there you go.

M.

Comment: This is *exactly* what I was looking for. Would mark it as correct 100x if I could, thanks!